# Spring Security with SwaggyDoc

Tags: grails, spring-security, swagger

I am using swaggydoc to provide an automated API site for my grails application along with Spring Security. I am using the grails rest controller along with grails 3.2.1 , spring security 3.0.3 and swaggydoc 3.0.2

The problem is, when I have spring security enabled I get a 403 on the swaggy page for the other controllers I'm trying to expose. I tried to do a few different security configurations to see if I can get it working, if I have all the controllers being login authentication it works, but that's not what I want. ***I want the public facing REST endpoint to be token authentication and then the API site for developers to be login authentication***. Ideally, I was wondering if there's a way for the other controllers under token authentication to have no authentication if the request is made by the SwaggyDoc controller's URI.

Here is my application.groovy,

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'cyberinform.LoginUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'cyberinform.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'cyberinform.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'cyberinform.AuthenticationToken'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = 401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName='password'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/blueapi'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true

grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', 'yyyy-MM-dd']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/**',               access: ['isFullyAuthenticated()']],
        [pattern: '/blueapi/**',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [

[ pattern: '/blueapi/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'],

[ pattern: '/**',
          filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter']
]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration)? If not would love to get your feedback on it.